# Creating 100 files

Tags: shell, ubuntu, scripting

So i want to create 100 files ( f1.txt - f100.txt ) and redirect in to the `/mnt/mydirectory and after that i want to add to this script pwgen 30 100 who generates 100 passwords each one with 30 characters and redirect each password in f1.txt

example:
 f1.txt contains 1 password with 30 characters numbers and letters

f2.txt contain the same

and i want to do this with pwgen 30 100 but i don`t know how to distribute each password in files

script.sh content:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /mnt/mydirectory/password{1..100}.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean by "redirect" them to a different directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ touch /mnt/yourdirectory/f{1..100}.txt
```

To incorporate your edits and stash a password into each file:

```
#!/bin/bash
passwords=( $(pwgen 10 30) )
index=1
for pw in "${passwords[@]}"; do
  echo "$pw" > "/mnt/yourdirectory/f${index}.txt"
  index=$((index+1))
done
```

Comment: this is worked but only with sudo

Comment: It would work for any user with privileges to write in the specified location.  Check the permissions on the mount.

Comment: and if i want to save 100 passwords each of them in f1.txt what should i do, a generated password have 30 characters(numbers and letters) and i want the first password to go in f1.txt the secound one in f2.txt ..100 pass - f100.txt i want to generated password with pwgen 30 100

Comment: and should i add this before touch.. or after? @DopeGhoti

Comment: You don't need to `touch` if you're immediately redirecting data into the files; the latter action will create the file if it does not exist.  But as with `touch`, you will need to run the script as a user with privileges to write in the destination location.

Comment: can you post the whole code in one comment because when i goes to the /mnt/mydirectory i  don`t have f1-f100.txt and when i run cat on f1.txt there is nothing inside

Comment: I have; see the second code block.  Put that into a file, execute it as a user who is able to write to the target location.

Comment: i want do do this in one sscript...

Comment: The second code block _is_ the entire script.  I don't know how much more clear I can make this.

Comment: yes sure, it was my fault thank men and have a good night i modifiy in code 10 30 to 30 100 because i want 30 charac and 100 passwords